# Installing Parallels Tools in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, parallels

**Problem**

When trying to install Parallels Tools in my Kali Linux VM it continues to fail because Kali mounts it with the `noexec` option. When I run `./install` it fails with a permission error.

**Example**

following the instructions from many places I,

`sudo su or su`

Make sure the DVD drive in the Linux VM is ejected:
`eject /dev/cdrom`

Go to the Parallels Desktop menu bar > Devices > CD/DVD > Connect image…
Navigate to `/Applications/Parallels Desktop/Contents/Resources/Tools`.

Click on prl-tools-lin.iso and click Open.

Mount the Parallels Tools image to the Linux VM:
`mkdir /media/cdrom`

`mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom`

Make sure the disk image has been successfully mounted:
`ls /media/cdrom`

It should list the files located on the disk:

`install*  installer/  install-gui*  kmods/  tools/  version`

Go to the Parallels Tools image and run the installation package:
`cd /media/cdrom`

`./install`

This results with a permission error or telling me that the disk is already mounted on `/media/cdrom0`.

**Question**

What is the proper way to mount the tools with the `exec` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing some basics here. The `mount` command must take a device and a mount path, unless the mount path is already defined in `/etc/fstab` in which case you can use only the mount path. Read up on with `man mount` or the many resources online.

In the screenshot you keep switching between `cdrom` and `cdrom0`, I'm not sure if it's just frustration and rushing, or if you expected them to be the same.

You almost got close to the answer with this command: `mount -o exec /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom`.
Kali mounts removable media with the `noexec` option, so you cannot execute any files on the CD image. Despite many tutorials telling you to unmount and mount the image again, you can actually remount in one command. Although you do need to get the syntax of the mount command right ;)

Without further ado:
`mount -o remount,defaults,ro,exec /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom`
The options used are:
`remount` - remount in place
`defaults` - because I don't want to bother with all the details
`ro` - read-only, it's a CDROM
`exec` - allow execution of files on this mount point.